# How to call a normal html page from mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to call a html page on click of  a button in mvc.
Is there any way to call a normal html page from mvc3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an anchor tag in your view, as you usually would:

```
<a href="/my-html-page.html">Click Me</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Then your button should look like:

```
<a href="path to html">Click me</a>
```

Comment: Should I add an exception in global.asax as routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.html/{*pathInfo}");?

Comment: @user1400915, No becouse you're not routing to it, it is just rendered directly to your html, and once the user clicked he will redirected to this page.